# Burpsuite page loading error after browser configuration

Tags: burp

After i configured firefox for Burpsuite and also downloaded the CA Certificate, but the browser is not able to load any http or https website.
The error is gives is: Unknow host: google.com. The same error is showing in the Burpsuite.
Not able to figure out!!

I tried using a different port, cleared browser cache, but did not work out